# How to resolve Android Studio error: Cannot find symbol method start

Tags: android, runnable, cannot-find-symbol

I created a basic Android Studio app from one of the templates and am trying to invoke a thread (Runnable) from the prebuilt handler in onCreate. All I've done is add the class that extends Runnable and then used the class in the handler.  Cannot figure out why I am getting the compile error:

**Cannot find symbol method start**

It's the only error and just on the line

```
new Thread(example.start());
```

The code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    static class GetExample implements Runnable
    {
        public void run()
        {    
            Log.i("GetExample class", "Inside GetExample::run()");
            return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                Log.i("Inside onCreate()", "TestBed -- onClick() invoked");

                try
                {
                    GetExample example = new GetExample();
                    new Thread(example.start());
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Log.i("Inside onCreate()", "TestBed -- IOException occurred");
                }
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
 . . .
```

Comment: `Thread`s `start()`; `Runnable`s `run()`.

Comment: @Makoto -- Are these docs by Oracle wrong?  They say use start().  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Take a *very* close look at where you're invoking `start()`.

Comment: @Makoto -- Arrgghhh.  I see it.  Would you add an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: It's not very clear what you need a `Thread` for, but I believe the Android way to do what you are wanting to do would be a `Handler`

Comment: I'm very reluctant to add it as an answer since, at best it's a typo; at worst you're missing something in terms of Android since I'm not well-versed in Android.  I'm leaning more on the side of "typo".

Comment: @Makoto - Understandable.  I marked as correct the first answer that solved the problem.  Others might possibly benefit from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Thread(new GetExample()).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have always used run for runnables and start for threads. 
The one that there is on the documentation that you put above, it is new Thread ( new Runnable()).start() , the method start is applied to the thread, not to the runnable object

So you can either use run(), or you can create a thread - new Thread and put the runnable object inside, just like in the example that was in the doc that you put in the comments. Then call start to the thread, not to the runnable.